# Solving x'=Ax for 4x4 matrix with repeated eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have the following matrix, with eigenvalue 2 (multiplicity 4). I am trying to solve x' = Ax, where A is the matrix shown above.

I know that the equation can be solved as follows:

$x(t) = e^{At}x_0 = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1}x_0 $

J is the Jordan canonical form of the matrix A:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I go about finding the eigenvectors in order to construct P and $P^{-1}$ in order to solve for x(t)? In addition, what is $e^{Jt}$ and how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need Jordan form  this time. Your matrix is of the form $A = 2I + N,$   where $N$ is the strict upper diagonal part as a square matrix, otherwise put $0.$ The two parts also commute, so
$$ e^A = e^{2I} e^N  $$  and
$$  e^{At}  = e^{2tI} e^{tN} $$
As $N$ is nilpotent, one can find the exponential from its (finite) Taylor series. Find $N, N^2, N^3.$ By my count $N^4 = 0.$

Note that the process with Jordan form is the same, you have a matrix $J = D + N$ with $N$ nilpotent, $D$ diagonal, and $DN=ND.$ The additional work is that it really is **necessary** to find a matrix $P$ such that $PJP^{-1} = A$ is the original matrix. Then $e^{At} = P e^{Dt} e^{Nt} P^{-1}.$ You **need** to find the actual matrix $P$ and its inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvectors are not going to cut it, your matrix is not diagonalizable. You'll need generalized eigenvectors.

Find an eigenvector by solving $(A-2I)x=0$ (or by observing your matrix). Then look for generalized eigenvectors which satisfy
$$(A-2I)^2x=0, (A-2I)^3x=0, (A-2I)^4x=0$$
You want them to be linearly independent. They form the matrix $P$.

$e^{Jt}$ is the exponential of $Jt$ that is
$$e^{Jt}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^nJ^n}{n!}$$
Since $J$ is not diagonal, $J^n$ is not so easily computed. You may write $J=2I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent to help with practical calculations.

Comment: Would the transposes of [1 0 0 0], [1 1 0 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 1 1 1] satisfy this here? By observation those seem like four valid generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes basically you have to recursively solve $(A-2I)x_1=0$, $(A-2I)x_2=x_1$... so these vectors work, the structure of $A$ is simple enough.

Comment: Okay, awesome. So then I would end up with something like:

$x(t) = e^{2t}Pe^{Nt}P^{-1}x_0$, and build P from those vectors.

Comment: Yes. As pointed out e^{Nt} will be a polynomial in $Nt$ since $N^4=0$.